Why Are Test Matches Ending in More Wins and Losses on Tougher Pitches Compared to the Past?
Why is Test cricket experiencing more wins and losses compared to draws on tougher pitches now than in the past? Are pitches becoming tougher than before? Many people claim that we are currently in an era of batting-friendly pitches, yet players like Pat Cummins and Kagiso Rabada have some of the best averages and strike rates in Test cricket.
